# ReactJS: Use Link in props instead of a-tag

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to use the `Link` from `react-router-dom` Component inside `props` instead of `a`-tag when the API sends an error to the frontend. Is this possible?

Code in React:

```
{
    errors.activateAccount && (
        <div className="invalid-feedback" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 
    errors.activateAccount}}/>
     )
}
```

Response from the Api:

```
if (!user.activated) {
  errors.activateAccount = 'Here comes the error message with a <a href="/">link</a>.';
  return res.status(400).send(errors);
}
```

Comment: Can you please replicate your components in codepen or jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

To my prespective, it's not a good option to do it via backend, you can simply pass a message and handle how it looks in the Front-End App, in this case, with React.

Response from API:

```
if (!user.activated) {
  errors.activateAccount = 'Simple Message';
  return res.status(400).send(errors);
}
```

In React App, you can get the response and do this in your component.

```
// inside render() Method
render() {
  if(errors.activateAccount.length > 0){
    // Now you return the message composed in Link Component.
    return <Link>{errors.activateAccount.message}</Link>
  } else {
    // Now you return your default component or anything you want
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks good, but i think it will not work in my case.
The problem is, that the error message coming from the api has a link inside the text. Just a part of it.

Comment: we can work on a function to extract the link from the message.

Comment: for your example response, ```'Here comes the error message with a <a href="/">link</a>.'.split(`<a href="`)[1].split(`">`)[0];``` this code can extract the link lying in `href` attribute in the `a-tag`